# Scala - Simple Mappings over Futures and Performance

Tags: scala, future

I did some performance analysis for scala `Future`s using the below snippets.

```
class Container(ec: ExecutionContext) {

  implicit val executionContext = ec

  def getInts: Future[Vector[Int]] = {
    Future {
      (1 to 100).toVector
    }
  }
}

implicit val ec = new ExecutionContext {
  val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100)
  // val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
  // I tried with both of the above threadPools

  def execute(runnable: Runnable) {
    threadPool.submit(runnable)
  }

  def reportFailure(t: Throwable) {}
}
```

Consider the following **trivial** snippets

**Snippet 1**

```
val container = new Container(ec)
val allIntsF = container.getInts

for {
  allInts <- allIntsF
} yield {
  val allIntsTransformed = allInts.map(i => 2 * i / 3)
  val allIntsFiltered = allIntsTransformed.filter(i => i > 50)
  allIntsFiltered.sum / allInts.length
}
```

**Snippet 2**

```
val container = new Container(ec)
val allIntsF = container.getInts
val allIntsTransformedF = allIntsF.map(v => v.map(i => 2 * i / 3))
val allIntsFilteredF = allIntsTransformedF.map(v => v.filter(i => i > 50))

for {
  allInts <- allIntsF
  allIntsTransformed <- allIntsTransformedF
  allIntsFiltered <- allIntsFilteredF
  // Assume that all 3 of these are needed for some calculation
} yield {
  allIntsFiltered.sum / allInts.length
}
```

According to the results, **Snippet 1** seems to be faster than the **Snippet 2**. It may be because of the less amount **context switches** compared to **Snippet 2**.

**Measurements**(Average time for 100 runs)

- With a Thread pool of 100 threads

  - Snippet 1 - 2.3 ms
  - Snippet 2 - 2.86 ms
- With a Thread pool of 3 threads

  - Snippet 1 - 1.36 ms
  - Snippet 2 - 1.8 ms
- Is this observation correct?
- What are the other interpretations/explanations that can be given to this result?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the measurements? Also, how did you do the benchmark? Just one iteration is not a good basis for comparison, although intuitively seems obvious that variant #1 should be faster (in variant two you map twice over `allIntsF` one in the for comprehension and one in `allIntsF.map...`, the same happens for `allIntsTransformed`, so logically it must be a tiny bit slower but if you had a lot of futures this could have added much more overhead)

Comment: Try rewriting the for comprehensions using the substitution model (by using a series of `flatMap`s and `map`) and you'll see yourself that there is duplication in the variant #2.

Comment: I ran it for 100 times and took the average time. I'll post the measurements later.

Comment: Agree with @NaderHadjiGhanbari: moving operations into the for comprehension in Snippet #2, is adding 2 flatMaps compared to snippet #1. Also, if I understand correctly, this instantiates a ThreadPool where only a single Future, i.e. a single thread runs. A bigger Thread pool is just more more management overhead and does not add anything to the computing "power"/parallelization

Comment: How did you actually "ran it for 100 times and took the average" ? The answer to this question is actually ver important here.